# TextBox on Canvas

Tags: java-me, canvas

I want to draw text-box on canvas.As i want to make registration form on that canvas.i don't want to use form.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a hard problem; you'll probably want to map the number keys to the letters or characters they represent (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517767/how-to-handle-keypressed-event-in-canvas-for-alphanumreic-using-j2me-midp2-0)).  This has two problems:

- Won't work on devices with QWERTY keyboards; you'd need to implement some way of detecting these
- (worse)  No predictive text.  This is fine for password input, and possibly just about acceptable for username input, but for entering any text of any length for any other purpose at all, you're really going to piss your users off if you can't use T9.

Better solution is to draw the text as a textbox on the canvas, but when the user activates it, switch from the canvas to a full-screen [TextBox](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextBox.html).  This allows the user to enter text as usual on the platform, making your life easier (no implementation of your own to debug).  You can even give it hints for what you want to enter, e.g. numbers or email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to implement canvas just for good GUI purpose then
you can go through framework.

Lot of frameworks available for j2me developing. I suggest [LWUIT](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/) is best for developing UI and use the [Resource Editor](http://www.themeswiki.org/Building_themes_using_LWUIT) for design the UI. If You need LWUIT latest source code checkout [here](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/source/browse/lwuit/) and build it. or they officially released [LWUIT 1.4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/tech/lwuit-141954.html). Some example application available in LWUIT repository and even LWUIT 1.4 package.

there are other frameworks also available in J2ME

[J2ME Polish](http://www.j2mepolish.org/) [J4ME](http://swik.net/J4ME)

Answer (score 0):

Try using scipt

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="200" style="border: 3px solid green;"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

      context.font = "italic bold 40pt Calibri";
      context.fillStyle = "red";
      context.strokeStyle = "blue";
      context.fillText("LUCKY", 100, 50);
      context.strokeText("LUCKY", 100, 100)
    </script>
```